# How to get inline element height with js, like span element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

```js
var mySpan=document.getElementById("mySpan");
alert(mySpan.height);
```

```html
<span id="mySpan" style="line-height:200px;">hello world</span>
```

But I get `undefined`. The Javascript can only get block or inline block element height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inline elements (and block as well), you can use offsetHeight. This will include vertical padding and borders as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.getComputedStyle(mySpan).lineHeight` to get value of line height of the element irrespective of whether the style is defined inline or in external CSS file.

```js
var mySpan=document.getElementById("mySpan");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(mySpan).lineHeight);
```

```html
<span id="mySpan" style="line-height:200px;">hello world</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS properties with a `-` are represented in camelCase in Javascript objects. Ex - `mySpan.style.lineHeight`.

You can also use bracket notation to access property. Ex - `mySpan.style['line-height']`

```js
var mySpan=document.getElementById("mySpan");
console.log(mySpan.style.lineHeight);
console.log(mySpan.style['line-height']);
```

```html
<span id="mySpan" style="line-height:200px;">hello world</span>
```

Comment: Line-height is not equal to height.How can i get height?

Comment: You can use `window.getComputedStyle(mySpan).height`